# design report perspective - eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse-rcp

i want to open the Design Report perspective from code (perhaps when I double click a report, the perspective should open) in a rcp eclipse application and I do not know where to start. 
could anyone help me and tell where to begin, what are the first steps.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
String perspId = "some.perspective.id";
IWorkbenchWindow w = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IPerspectiveRegistry reg = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry();
w.getActivePage().setPerspective(reg.findPerspectiveWithId(perspId));
```